# I have an issue while running on visual studio code. : C++ declaration is incompatible with,

Tags: c++

This is my source code and I got an error
" C++ declaration is incompatible with (declared at line 36) "
and
C++ identifier "Node" is undefined.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class K
{
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node() 
        {
            next = prev = nullptr;
        }
        Node(int _x)
            : Data(_x)
        {
            next = prev = nullptr;
        }
        int Data;
        Node* next, *prev;
    };
public:
    K() 
    {
        std::cout << "\n\t Hi, I am K \n";
    }
    ~K()
    {
        std::cout << "\n\t Bye, i Was K \n";
    }
    void Call(int _x)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\t Called K" << _x << "\n";
    }

    Node* GetNode();

};

template <typename T>
class Node;
template <typename T>
Node* K<T>::GetNode() // Here I get error 
{

}
```

So, I added

```
template <typename T>
class Node;
```

then the second error disappears but still, the first error left. I am not sure what is wrong with this code. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `GetNode` is within class `K`, so there `Node` refers to the inner class `K<T>::Node`.

Your definition is outside the class, so the return type is not looked up within the class scope, and thus not found. If you add the extra declaration of `Node`, it finds the name, but then there are two other problems: that outer `Node` needs a template parameter, and it's simply a *different* `Node` than the one inside `K`.

First, remove the `template <typename T> class Node;` declaration, it's simply incorrect.

Second, you need to make the return type refer to the correct `Node`. There's two ways of doing this.

The easy way, since C++11, is to use trailing return type syntax.

```
template <typename T>
auto K<T>::GetNode() -> Node*
{
}
```

The trailing return type comes after the scope specifier `K<T>::`, so the compiler knows to look up the name within `K<T>`.

The second option is to explicitly reference the `Node` within `K<T>`, but it's a dependent type, so the syntax is horrible:

```
template <typename T>
typename K<T>::Node* K<T>::GetNode()
{
}
```

I strongly recommend the first way, unless you're working in a pre-C++11 codebase.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help..!

Comment: I may be old-fashioned but I think it is important to write out and understand the second example because that's what's actually happening (*this* is which `Node` we are talking about and yes, it *is*, for better or worse, a dependent name!).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica "because that's what's actually happening" - I wouldn't describe it that way. It's not like the compiler transforms the trailing return type version into the classical version.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Well, to the degree that it deduces the type that's spelled out in the pre-C++11 code, it does! Obviously. Don't you agree? As you say yourself: because the trailing return type may be in the scope of the function declaration it finds `K<T>::Node`.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Would you also teach new programmers to write the declaration in the class as `K::Node GetNode()`, or to write a definition of a function with a parameter as `void K<T>::AddNode(typename K<T>::Node node)`, so they know "what's really happening"? The only thing that's special about the return type is that the weird parsing rules of C++ place it outside the scope of the function being defined.